# Correct way to remove last grapheme of CharSequence

Tags: java, charsequence

The code:

```kotlin
val plainText = "plainText"
val plainTextWithEmoji = "plainText"

println("plainText=$plainText, length=${plainText.length}")
println("plainTextWithEmoji=$plainText, length=${plainTextWithEmoji.length}")

// Output:
// plainText=plainText, length=9
// plainTextWithEmoji=plainText, length=15
```

This code imply that emoji character's length is **2**, not **1**.

When I want to remove the last character's:

If I call `plainText.subSequence(0, plainTextWithEmoji.length - 1)`, the result is wrong, because emoji character length is more than 1.

To call subSequence and get the correct result, do this: `plainText.subSequence(0, plainTextWithEmoji.length - 2)`

But in general, We can not know **if the last character's length is 1**. When we want to remove the last character, simply call `charSequence.subSequence(0, charSequence.length - 1)` will return a wrong result.

So, it is any way to remove last grapheme of CharSequence? Thx!

Comment: if you will use UTF32 encoding for emoji and text you should see that each of them have same size, should be 4. also proper emoji should be 16-bit hex code, so U+0061 = (binary)0000 0000 0110 0001. so it should have length of 4 in UTF-8 encoding, i wonder why it's only 2 in your example

Comment: @Szprota21 that emoji is `U+1F970`, so it actually takes two UTF "characters".

Comment: What language is that? Java doesn't have those string formatting features.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I find the solution inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59762318/10815621). Since UTF-8 is variable length, to call `CharSequence.subSequence` and get correct result, we can get every grapheme's start index in this sentence by magic `BreakIterator`:

```kotlin
fun CharSequence.removeLast(): CharSequence {
    val graphemeStartIndexes = computeGraphemesStartIndexes(this)
    return this.subSequence(0, graphemeStartIndexes.last())
}

private fun computeGraphemesStartIndexes(sequence: CharSequence): List<Int> {
    val breakIterator = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance()
    breakIterator.setText(sequence.toString())
    val graphemesStartIndexes = mutableListOf<Int>()

    val start = breakIterator.first()
    graphemesStartIndexes.add(start)
    while (breakIterator.next() != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        graphemesStartIndexes.add(breakIterator.current())
    }
    return graphemesStartIndexes.apply { removeAt(size - 1) }
}
```

Example:

```kotlin
val plainTextEmojiSequence = "Hello"
val plainTextOnlySequence = "Hi~!"

println(plainTextEmojiSequence.removeLast()) // "Hello"
println(plainTextOnlySequence.removeLast())  // "Hi~"
```

Comment: This is not techinically related to UTF-8, but the rest of the answer is correct. There's two issues: first String use UTF-16 so a single Unicode codepoint can stretch over two `char` values and second multiple Unicode codepoints can make up a single grapheme. Your code solves both of those.

Comment: @GenerousBadger Thank you for you to help me located the issue clearly. `BreakIterator` can detect single grapheme is make up by one or two codepoints. so by calling `BreakIterator` we can remove any grapheme at the sentence correctly :)